# Array value at index 0 changes at end of loop in C

Tags: c, arrays

Below is my C code. I dont have a clue as to why the value at index 0 in array mins (as well as for meds and maxs) changes on the last iteration of loop. Please help.

Sorry for adding too many print statements. Those were mostly for debugging.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SZ 10000

typedef long long LL;


LL min(LL x, LL y)
{
    return x<y?x:y;
}

LL max(LL x, LL y)
{
    return x>y?x:y;
}

struct triangle
{
    LL sm, md, lg;
};

int main()
{
    int n, i, ans;
    struct triangle obj[n];
    LL mins[n], meds[n], maxs[n];
    LL a, b, c;
    scanf("%d%*c", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld%*c", &a, &b, &c);
        printf("Scanned : %lld%lld%lld\n", a, b, c);
        obj[i].sm = mins[i] = min(a, min(b,c));
        obj[i].lg = maxs[i] = max(a, max(b, c));
        obj[i].md = meds[i] = max(min(a,b), min(max(a,b),c));
        printf("min : %lld\t med = %lld\t max = %lld\n", mins[i], meds[i], maxs[i]);
        printf("min[0] = %lld\n", mins[0]);
    }

    printf("Outside : min[0] = %lld\n", mins[0]);
    printf("mins : ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%lld ", mins[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("meds : ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%lld ", meds[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("maxs : ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%lld ", maxs[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //printf("%d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How large is `n`? You might have stack overflow invoking undefined behaviour. Never rely on external input! Check for an acceptable range, but better dynamically allocate the arrays. See [ask], provide **all** necessary information. And strip down the code to a [mcve].

Comment: Which loop? How it changes? Can you post the output and provide minimal complete?

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and treat them as errors.

Answer (score 4):

You used uninitialized and indeterminate `n` to deside the size of arrays. Declare arrays after reading `n` like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, ans;
    LL a, b, c;
    if(scanf("%d%*c", &n) != 1) {
        fputs("failed to read n\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    struct triangle obj[n];
    LL mins[n], meds[n], maxs[n];
```